# how to make datagridview column as linktype

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am fetching data and storing in datatable to display it in datatgridview ,How do I make 2nd column `visitdate` of datatable as of `link type`?
something like this

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn linkcol = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
this.dataGridViewVisits.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle = linkcol;
```

below is my code for displaying data in datagridview

```
cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select VisitNo,VisitDate,remark from Patient_Visit_Details WHERE Patient_ID=" + pid, con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
            adp1.Fill(dt);
            this.dataGridViewVisits.DataSource = dt;
            DataGridViewLinkColumn linkcol = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code after you have set the DataTable(dt) as your DataGridView's datasource.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewVisits.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
                linkCell.Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                row.Cells[1] = linkCell;
            }
```

It'll surely work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `DataBindingComplete` event of datagridView like the following.

```
  private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                r.Cells[1] = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
            }
        }
```

Comment: as i am new to this ,can u tell how this handle will get triggered than?

Comment: In visual Studio click on DataGridGrid in properties window click on event icon look at event list look for DataBindingComplete.
Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

for Vb.Net geeks...

```
For Each typeCell As DataGridViewRow In FlxInvTransaction.Rows
    Dim linkCell As New DataGridViewLinkCell
    linkCell.Value = typeCell.Cells(2).Value
    typeCell.Cells(2) = linkCell
Next
```

Answer (score -2):

**Hi,**

**You just need to create HyperLink column in GridView control using smart navigation and set values as like below...**

> ```
>  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="VisitDate"
>  DataTextField="VisitDate"
>  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Default3.aspx?VisitNo={0}&visitDt={1}" />
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**

Comment: Please tell me the code in c# ,as I am coding in c# ,Check the tag